what's the relationship between the eigenvalues of $\phi_g$ and a certain set of $H$-representations $(W,\rho)$

Let $g\in G$ be an element in a finite group G and H the subgroup generated by g. For a given irreducible G-representation $(V,\phi)$ over $\mathbb{C}$, what's the relationship between the eigenvalues of $\phi_g$ and the set of $H$-representations $(W,\rho)$ such that $Ind_H^G\rho$ contains an invariant subspace equivalent to $(V,\phi)$?

I know that $Ind_H^G\rho$ is defined here, but the definition seems hard to work with. I'm not sure how to describe the set of H-representations $(W,\rho)$ so that $Ind_H^G \rho$ has an invariant subspace equivalent to $(V,\phi)$, but I'm pretty sure this'll be useful to know.

${\rm Ind}_H^G W$ contains a copy of $V$ precisely if: $$\langle{\rm Ind}_H^G W,V\rangle>0$$
By Frobenius reciprocity $\langle{\rm Ind}_H^G W,V\rangle=\langle W,{\rm Res}_H^G(V)\rangle$.
As $g$ generates $H$, we know that $W$ and ${\rm Res}_H^G(V)$ are direct sums of $1$ dimensional representations determined by the eigenvalues of $\phi_g, \rho_g$ respectively.
So ${\rm Ind}_H^G W$ contains a copy of $V$ precisely when $\langle{\rm Ind}_H^G W,V\rangle=\langle W,{\rm Res}_H^G(V)\rangle>0$, which happens precisely when the eigenvalues of $\phi_g$ and $\rho_g$ overlap.
If you have not seen Frobenius reciprocity before, the proof is:

Let $\chi,\psi$ be the characters of $V, W$ respectively.  From your link we have that the character of  ${\rm Ind}_H^G W$ on some $g\in G$ is given by:
$$\sum_{x\in G/H|x^{-1}gx\in H} \psi(x^{-1}gx)=\frac1{|H|}\sum_{x\in G|x^{-1}gx\in H} \psi(x^{-1}gx)$$
Thus $$
\langle{\rm Ind}_H^G W,V\rangle=
\frac1{|G||H|}\sum_{g\in G} \overline{\chi(g)}\left(\sum_{x\in G|x^{-1}gx\in H} \psi(x^{-1}gx)\right)$$
$$
=\frac1{|G||H|}\sum_{g\in G,h\in H, g\sim h} \overline{\chi(g)}\psi(h) C(h)
$$
$$
=\frac1{|G||H|}\sum_{h\in H} \overline{\chi(h)}\psi(h) C(h)C_h
=\frac1{|H|}\sum_{h\in H} \overline{\chi(h)}\psi(h) 
$$
$$
=\langle W,{\rm Res}_H^G(V)\rangle
$$
by the orbit-stabilizer theorem.  Here $C(h)$ denotes the centraliser of $h$ and $C_h$ denotes the conjugacy class of $h$.  Also $g\sim h$ denotes $g$ is conjugate to $h$.

